# Maximum number of articles that can be created in WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I know this has something to do with MySQL databases and I don't have much knowledge in it. Can someone help me to give a rough idea about how many articles can be written? I read an article about Joomla maximum articles in the link given below. Is it same as Joomla ?

http://www.itoctopus.com/maximum-number-of-articles-categories-and-users-on-joomla

[image: Picture of wordpress database]

Picture of WordPress database

Comment: @LeventeNagy you mean 4 billion articles ? its same for bigint ?

Comment: Your answer is in the article.... And this has nothing to do with wordpress or joomla, yes it has to do with database, What they try to point out is the ID, The id is an unique identifier which is auto incremented. That has a limit, Integer can go as high as 2147483647. If unsigned it can be 4294967295. Get it?

Comment: @LeventeNagy ok i got it...thanks